# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt - in some PC

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I make a software in VS2013 and it has a database in MSSQL2014. When I run it in my PC(my OC's OS is windows-7 64-bit), software work (if database is in my PC or other PC in Local Network) but when I want to run it in other PC (specially some PC with windows-7 32-bit it has problem when it want to connect to database - when it want to load forms it doesn't have problems).

```
       SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new sqlConnection("Server=192.168.100.18;Database=test;User Id=sa;Password=111;");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM test";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        sqlConnection1.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Ok");
```

when program run when the code sqlConnection1.Open(); want to execute it has an error:

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt
```

but it work without error in some other PC in local Network

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293032/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an-indication-that-oth ?

Comment: thanks about link - i checked but unfortunately didn't help me to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

fortunately I can find problem. .NET FrameWork version 4.5.1 has a problem. I changed the version to 4 or 4.5 and the problem solved