# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. Windows forms

Tags: windows, winforms

I am getting the exception

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

When opening a window from a windows form. The strange thing is it is occurring only in one system(client). I tested the application on my system and it works without any exception.

Stack trace is below

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.HostedTextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& message)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I am using the following way to open the sub form

```
subform = new subform(parameters)
subform.show();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The stack trace says that you need to call Telerik for support.  Be sure to do a better job than you did here, they'll ignore you if you don't have a minimum repro project available that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You encountered an issue which is quite present in the interwebz but there's almost no solution for it. I had those exceptions as well in an app of mine but they occured infrequently and unreproducable.

Probably the machine your application is running on has problems with a memory module, probably it is running on Citrix and any unsafe PInvokes are failing or you're using 3rd party control suites with internal issues.

I found those message with a lot of different call stacks in different circumstances, but all of them had to do with UI drawing like your stacktrace above.

I don't think you'll find your answer here - try Google and check some of the following articles:

- [social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f48c152-68cd-45ec-a11e-baa7de7f79c3/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory?forum=csharpgeneral)
- [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293032/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an-indication-that-oth)
- [forums.textcontrol.com](http://forums.textcontrol.com/showthread.php?324479-Attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory)

Good luck.